# Where Do I Specify the URL for Generic Publish Option in electron-builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to set up an Electron project to auto-update. I'm trying to follow the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Auto-Update).

Step 2 is [Configure Publish](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Publishing-Artifacts#PublishConfiguration) and this is completely confusing me. I want to set up the auto-update to download from our own website, so I'm trying to set up publishing using the "generic" option. So I set it up the "build" property on the package.json as this:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "foo.desktop.app",
    "productName": "My Desktop App",
    "asar": true,
    "win": {
      "iconUrl": "https://example.com/path/to.ico",
      "publish": ["generic"]
    }
  },
```

Now when I run `build`, electron-builder says:

```
Error: Please specify "url" for "generic" update server
```

Where do I specify the URL? I can't figure it out, and the documentation isn't helping at all.

Comment: `{"provider": "generic", "url": "your URL"}` instead of "generic"

Comment: @develar is publishing to generic deprecated? It doesn't seem to be doing that step or is it necessary to implement custom code somewhere for generic? The current docs could do a bit better to explain. Since electron-builder is not supporting Bitbucket or Gitlab there must be manual integration with those CI pipelines and auto-update functionality of artifacts hosted there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delvar gave me the answer in the comment:

```
{"provider": "generic", "url": "your URL"}
```

Comment: how url should be ? to know witch gitlab repo? as setFeedURL is deprecated!